# extract number from string from another file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, extract

I am currently working on a batch file that is supposed to read a version number from another file.

Basically, I just need to extract the string from the other document and get the number from it (number changes over time).

```
set dir=..\folder1\file1.vcxproj

:: I want to get a string from %dir% with a specific beginning and then extract the version number from it
set string=... ("<PlatformToolset>*")
set vernum=... ("..>v142<..)
```

Thats what I want to achieve:

```
echo %string%
   <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
echo %vernum%
   142
```

I hope I could describe my problem. Unfortunately I have little experience with cmd and it is difficult for me to articulate myself in this respect.

I hope someone can still help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir` is a poor name for a variable for two reasons. First `dir` is a keyword in batch, and then it implies that it's a directory when it seems to be a file.

Use `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Quotes are not needed for setting arithmetic values (`set /a`)

So presuming that what you're doing is to extract the `142` from the string
    `<PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>` found in the file `dir` (please change that name)

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=<> " %%b in ('type "%dir%"') do if "%%b"=="PlatformToolset" set "vernum=%%c"
set "vernum=%vernum:~1%"
```

note that the location and quote type (`'` or `"`) are critical.

The `for` reads each line of the file and analyses that line, assigning the first "token" (1) to `%%b` and the second (2) to `%%c`.

The line is regarded as being
<delimiter sequence><token1><delimiter sequence><token2><delimiter sequence><token3><delimiter sequence><token4>

A *delimiter sequence* is one or more of any of the characters specified in the `delims=` option; in this case, <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>

So - where `%%a` (token 1) is `PlatformToolset`, we want to assign `%%c` (token 2) to `vernum`

so `vernum` will become `v142` with a file containing the test line you've posted.

And the hieroglyphics behind the `set` command is explained by `set /?` from the prompt - it takes the value in `vernum`, starting at "character 1" (where the character numbering starts at **0**) and assigns the result to the variable `vernum`

for more detail about `for` gymnastics, see `for /?` from the prompt.

Comment: nice it works. thank you very much for helping and explaining!